# Strange problem with Google App Engine Java Mail

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the MailService feature of Google App Engine in my 
application.  It works fine in one application without any issues. 
But the same code doesn't work in another app. I'm not able to figure 
it out.  Please help.  Following is the piece of code that I use to 
send mail.

```
public static void sendHTMLEmail(String from, String fromName, String 
to, String toName, String subject, String body) { 
                _logger.info("entering ..."); 
                Properties props = new Properties(); 
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
                _logger.info("got mail session ..."); 
                String htmlBody = body; 
                try { 
                        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
                        _logger.info("created mimemessage ..."); 
                        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, 
                                        fromName)); 
                        _logger.info("from is set ..."); 
                        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress( 
                                        to, toName)); 
                        _logger.info("recipient is set ..."); 
                        msg.setSubject(subject); 
                        _logger.info("subject is set ..."); 
                        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart(); 
                        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
                htmlPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html"); 
                mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart); 
                        _logger.info("body part added ..."); 


                msg.setContent(mp); 
                        _logger.info("content is set ..."); 
                        Transport.send(msg); 
                        _logger.info("email sent successfully."); 
                } catch (AddressException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (MessagingException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
                } 
        }
```

When I look at the log (on the server admin console), it prints the 
statement "content is set ..." and after that there is nothing in the 
log.  The mail is not sent.  At times I get the following error after 
the above statement is printed (and the mail is not sent).

com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer 
getInheritableThreadLocalsField: Couldn't access 
Thread.inheritableThreadLocals. Reference finalizer threads will 
inherit thread local values.

But the mail quota usage keeps increasing.

Remember, this works fine in one application, but not in other.  I'm 
using the same set of email addresses in both the apps (for from and 
to).

I'm really stuck with this.  Appreciate any help.

Thank you. 
Velu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the exceptions? I bet one of them is being thrown - your printStackTrace will go nowhere.